# Get the type of field in django template

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using django forms and I want to use Twitter Bootstrap's css in my html.
so my template looks like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ field.label_tag }}<!--Same thing as : <label for="{{field.id_for_label}}"></label> -->

        <input type="{{field.type}}" class="form-control" id="{{field.auto_id}}" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't figure out out to get the type value. `{{field.type}}` .

Is there any way to get the type of the input field in django templates?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**
The reason I am asking this question is because I want to be able to apply bootstrap classes to the input element. But in Bootstrap3, to use the default css for input types you would have to add form-control class to the input element like so: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{field.auto_id}}" placeholder="">.`

If I use django's field `{{field}}` then I can't add the form-control class. 
I hope this clarifies some things.

I also saw this app https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3 that looks like it does what I wanted to do. It surprises me that django doesn't allow accessing the form type to allow more flexibility.

Comment: Typically, you would just do something like:
    `<div class="form-group"> {{ field }} </div>`
The type will be filled in automatically by Django.  Do you need the type for some other purpose?

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard Yes. But in Bootstrap3, to use the default css for input types you would have to add form-control class to the input element like so: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{field.auto_id}}" placeholder="">`  What I really wanted to do was to apply form-control class in the template itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get type of Django form widget from within template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809874/get-type-of-django-form-widget-from-within-template)

Answer (score 43):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31538555/254553

You can use:

```
{{ [FIELD].field.widget.input_type }}
```

`[FIELD]` is your field name.

Comment: This should be an accepted answer!

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you need to worry about the `field_type`. Django will itself handle that for you depending on the form field.

Lets say we have a `ContactForm` like:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
    cc_myself = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Then `{{form.subject}}` will automatically create `<input>` element in the template.

```
<input id="id_subject" type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" />
```

Similarly, `{{form.message}}` in the template will create:

```
<input type="text" name="message" id="id_message" />
```

**Though if you really need to get the form field type in the template, you can create a custom template filter like below.**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='field_type')
def field_type(field):
    return field.field.widget.__class__.__name__
```

Now, in your template, you need to do something like:

```
{{form.field_name|field_type}}
```

In the above example, `{{form.message|field_type}}` will return `TextInput`.

Comment: True! I wanted more flexibility with my input elements  though. Mostly to be able to use bootstrap classes in the template itself.

Comment: Updated the ans with a custom template filter which will return the field_type.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the field type then refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1809982).
If you want to override the default type of the field, use `attrs` parameter when defining the widget for the field.
Eg.

```
field_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'type': 'custom type'}))
```

Also note that you can pass any key value pair to `attrs` and they will be used as attributes in the html tag when the form is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. I used Django Widget Tweaks to add classes (https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks).

Then you can do something like this:

```
    {% for field in form %}
     <div class="form-group {% if field.errors %}has-error {% endif %}">    
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
        {% if field.errors %}
        <span class="help-block">{{ field.errors.0 }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
   {% endfor %}
```

I think another way of dealing with this is to use django crispy forms but I have not tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to override the `__init__` method of the form in order to pass attributes to the HTML without having to know the type of field. Works with both standard forms and modelforms

```
class CoolForm(forms.Form):
    field_name = forms.CharField(...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CoolForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control'
        }
```

You can pass any HTML attribute through to the template this way, for example `'placeholder': 'email@exam.pl'`