# How to exclude specific field types in a template form loop

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using `django_widget_tweaks` to loop over form fields:

```
  {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">{{ field.label }}</label>

      {% if form.is_bound %}
        {% if field.errors %}
          {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              {{ error }}
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
        {% endif %}
      {% else %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if field.help_text %}
        <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

This displays a happy Bootstrap4 compliant interface, except when displaying fields like `radio` when I need to use a `custom-control` class not the `form-control` class.

How can I filter the form field loop to exclude radio inputs so I can write this code separately?

I need to understand how to filter the field loop and what the correct way to do this with the field type for `radio` is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the type of field in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569563/get-the-type-of-field-in-django-template) - Take a look at Rahul Gupta answer.

Comment: @PedramParsian Thanks but unfortunately no, that just tells me how to get the field type. I need to know how to exclude it from the for loop.

Comment: Can you not just add another `if` to the template that detects radio inputs and renders the field differently?